# Avoid memory leaks in C++ Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
void append(char*& input,const char* str){
  size_t input_len = strlen(input);
  size_t str_len = strlen(str);

  size_t len = input_len + str_len;
  char* temp = new char[len + 1];

  memcpy(temp, input, input_len);
  memcpy(temp + input_len, str, str_len);
  // **#3** delete[] input;
  temp[len] = '\0';
  input = temp;
}
int main(){
  char* s = "string";

  cout << s << endl;
  append(s, " hello"); // **#1** not initialized by an array
  cout << s << endl;
  append(s, " welcome"); // **#2** now having an array
  cout << s << endl;
}
```

I want to delete previous allocated array **(#3)** after assigning new one. But at first time **(#1)** calling its a pointer with dynamic allocation.

How can I avoid such memory leaks?
Is there a way to identify memory allocation with 'new'? or other?

```
    if(p == new char[])...
```

look at this, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/ it change the original string

Comment: Short answer: you can avoid memory leaks by freeing the memory you have previously allocated.

Comment: Short and simple answer: *Don't* use pointers! In your case, working with strings, you should use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.

Comment: in general, `std::unique_ptr` look it up. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: If you still insist on using raw pointers, instead of passing `input` by reference and modifying where it points, *return* the new pointer instead, and leave `input` be. Then let the caller free the memory using the returned pointer.

Comment: The append function for std::string is named +.

Comment: Use [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization)!

Comment: `char* s = "string";` <= **never do this**, always do this: `const char* s = "string";` if you turn your compiler's warnings on it should complain.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i want to do it using pointers, not strings

Comment: look at this, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/ it change the original string

Comment: *Why* do you want to use pointers? In modern C++ there's seldom any need for pointers except for polymorphism. With `std::string` you just do `return input + str` and be done with it, or not have the function at all. No hassle, it works, it works well, and it doesn't matter how large or small the strings are. And most importantly you don't have to worry about memory leaks!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i want to use simple C++ or pure C. Because I'm using this for programming some hardware components

Comment: If you need to pass a pointer to the string, you can still use `std::string`. When writing programs, go for easy, simple, and maintainable and working code. Then you measure and benchmark and test to make sure it follows all requirements. If there's some problem *then* you can start thinking about going lower-level or optimizations. Don't do it before you actually need to.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you reinvent the wheel, why not use arrays and [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat)? Using fixed-sized arrays is usually also a good idea on very small embedded systems, as dynamic memory allocation can easily lead to out-of-memory conditions. So you're doing it wrong either way by not using the facilities provided to you by C++, or by using dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude cool thanks

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i'll try [strcat](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i have change my code as [this](https://ideone.com/LBsUSH) can you pls reply me about it

Comment: @KevinAlex C++ is very well suited for low-level embedded programming if you have a compiler available. There is a great book Real-time C++: Efficient Object-Oriented And Template Microcontroller Programming: https://www.amazon.com/Real-Time-Efficient-Object-Oriented-Microcontroller-Programming/dp/3642346871.

Answer (score 1):

I follow some simple rules:

- don't do manual memory allocations. If you find yourself writing a manual `delete`, stop and think twice.
- use `std::string` instead of C-style strings
- use `std::vector<T>` instead of C-arrays (or `std::array<T>` for fixed-sized arrays)
- use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` by default
- use `std::shared_ptr` if necessary
- use RAII wrappers for other resources, e.g. files

Your code can be written as simple as

```
// With C++17, we could use std::string_view for the input parameters
// I strongly prefer pure functions that don't mutate their arguments
std::string append(std::string const& s1, std::string const& s2) {
    return s1 + s2;
}

// the same function mutating the input argument. 
void append_mutate(std::string& s1, std::string const& s2) {
    s1 += s2;
}

int main(){
  std::string s = "string";

  cout << s << endl;
  s = append(s, " hello");
  cout << s << endl;
  append2(s, " welcome");
  cout << s << endl;
}
```

I would also strongly advice against using C-style strings and especially C strings.If you are coming from a C background or don't have much experience with C++, I would recommend [A Tour of C++](https://isocpp.org/tour).

The idea of these classes is an example of [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization). The basic principle is to encapsulate resources, e.g. memory or files, into wrapper classes that own the resource and take care of acquisition and release in the constructor/destructor. This provides exception-safe, deterministic resource handling.

Comment: You forgot: use `std::vector` instead of pointers for dynamic arrays other than strings

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, added it to the list